# '*' around parentheses : pointers

Tags: c, pointers

Consider this code for qsort:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int values[] = { 88, 56, 100, 2, 25 };

int cmpfunc(const void * a, const void * b)
{
    return *(int*)a - *(int*)b;
}

int main()
{
    int n;

    printf("Before sorting the list is: \n");
    for (n = 0; n < 5; n++)
    {
        printf("%d ", values[n]);
    }

    qsort(values, 5, sizeof(int), cmpfunc);

    printf("\nAfter sorting the list is: \n");
    for (n = 0; n < 5; n++)
    {
        printf("%d ", values[n]);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

what does `*(int*)a` means specifically? It looks like a pointer to a pointer? why cant i do:

```
**a // dereferrencing twice would get the value, no?
```

or

```
*(int *a) // looks about the same. Also why do i need the int?
```

apologies if this question seemed obvious as I've been looking at this for hours now, and i still cant grasp why that '*' is wrapping around the bracket.

Comment: You could also, for readability: `const int * ia = a; const int * ib = b; return *ia - *ib;`. No casts needed anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`void*` and `const void*` are used in C to stand in for a generic pointer of unknown type. `qsort` doesn't really know what it's sorting: the callback comparison function `cmpfunc` does that task. But C is statically-typed, so the callback function needs to have a specific prototype. That's where `const void*` is useful.

Of course, within your supplied `cmpfunc`, *you* know the type of object being sorted, so you are able to *cast* the `const void*` to your type. That is what `(int*)` is doing: it's a cast.

Technically you should cast to `const int*` instead:

`return *(const int*)a - *(const int*)b;`

Casting away `const` *can* cause you trouble.

Answer (score 2):

A pointer to `void` can't be dereferenced. Therefore, in the given case it must have to cast to `int *` before dereferencing.

In `*(int*)a`, `(int*)` is casting `a` to pointer to `int` and then `*` outside the parenthesis dereferencing the value at that address.